# GUI for running graph algorithms on Mac OS X

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Is there a graphical user interface/program which can be used to show graph algorithms being executed for Mac OS X Mountain Lion? I've asked a lot o people and googled a lot, to no avail. I'm sorry if this is not exactly a coding issue, but I think the answer will help a lot of people who also need to teach this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the [R project](http://www.r-project.org/).  There are some useful graphic tools that I experimented with, before I realized that for my graph computations I was going to need a much more powerful (and faster) compiled version.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out about the [GraphStream](http://graphstream-project.org/) Java library from rlegendi's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359557/java-graph-layout-algorithms) question. I haven't had a chance to download it yet, but the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XX5rRF6uxow) looks promising.