# Java graph layout algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, layout, graphviz

In my Java application, i need some sort of a layout algorithm. The first approach is as follows:

- Graphviz package needs to be installed
- Create a dot file
- Call graphviz from java application and parse output (layout)
- Show the graph with the layout from graphviz (attributed dot)

But this solution requires the graphviz package installed on the running machines. I want to get rid of this dependency and i am searching for an adequate replacement.

- Input: Nodes with width and height / edges from node to node with a thickness of the line
- Output: Surrounding bounding box size, positions for nodes and edges

Can you recommend any good and simple java layout algorithm? Do you have any experiences?

Thanks

Comment: for directed graphs i used sugiyama framework, i never worked with non directed graphs so i'm not sure what is best for them, you can also have a look at force directed graphs

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend using the [GraphStream API](http://graphstream-project.org/). It handles the DOT format and the visualization is quite nice.

- Watch it in action [in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XX5rRF6uxow)
- See the file input [demo here](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Reading-files-using-FileSource_1.0/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use recently open-sourced [graph-support](https://github.com/jamisonjiang/graph-support) which is a java version of tiny graphviz.